# VB Userform: How to search for a word in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a search criteria based on a column, but I have to type in every single word within that cell, but I would like to search on a word or a few words within that cell. Is this possible?

```
Public CallDetails As Collection

Public Function Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As String) As Collection

Dim rng_to_search As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim FoundItem As clsCallDetails

Set CallDetails = New Collection

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set rng_to_search = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

With rng_to_search
    'Look for the first instance.
    Set rFound = .Find(what:=NumberToFind, _
                       after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = rFound.Address
        Do
            Set FoundItem = New clsCallDetails 'Create a new instance of the class to hold the details.
            With FoundItem
                .Title = rFound.Offset(, 5)
                .LoggedBy = rFound.Offset(, 1) 'Offset from column A by 1 column, so column B.
                .CallNumber = rFound.Offset(, 2)
                .DateField = rFound.Offset(, 3)
                .OwnerField = rFound.Offset(, 4)
                .Description = rFound.Offset(, 6)
                .Solution = rFound.Offset(, 7)
                .URLImage = rFound.Offset(, 8)

            End With
            CallDetails.Add FoundItem 'Add the class instance to our collection.
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound) 'Look for the next value.

        'Continue searching until we reach the top again.
        Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.  The tags contain *words* to help you select only the relevant ones.

Comment: Okay my bad. I have removed it

Comment: Not sure, but may be `LookAt:=xlPart` is what you need.